Regarding a conversation in Trollope's Doctor Thorne
At the end of the tenth chapter of Doctor Thorne by Anthony Trollope, Sir Roger Scatcherd says to the doctor:

You need not give yourself the least trouble in the world about my will till I'm dead; not the least. And who knows—may be, I may be settling your affairs yet; eh, doctor? looking after your niece when you're dead and gone, and getting a husband for her, eh? Ha! ha! ha!

However, it seemed clear from the beginning of the story that Roger was unaware of the fact that Mary is living with her uncle. How to solve this apparent contradiction?

He was unaware at the beginning of the story. The summary on the Trollope Society website says:

After a particularly violent attack of delirium tremens, Sir Roger asked the Doctor to be trustee for his fortune, explaining that his son Louis would inherit and after him the oldest child of his sister in America. The doctor was thus forced to reveal Mary Thorne’s identity.

This happens in Chapter 13 'The Two Uncles'. Dr Thorne, having thought deeply about it, decides to tell Sir Roger that his sister's illegitimate daughter is alive and known to him.

At last a light seemed to break in upon Sir Roger's mind. Dr Thorne,
he perceived, did not answer his last question. He perceived, also,
that the doctor was affected with some more than ordinary emotion. Why
should it be that this subject of Mary Scatcherd's child moved him so
deeply? Sir Roger had never been at the doctor's house at
Greshamsbury, had never seen Mary Thorne, but he had heard that there
lived with the doctor some young female relative; and thus a
glimmering light seemed to come in upon Sir Roger's bed.

It's not clear why he had specified 'niece' in the earlier conversation; presumably he thought the most likely 'young female relative' to be living with a bachelor was a niece.
Also, Mary was niece to both men (as the chapter title indicates), so if he had known it was Mary he wouldn't have called her 'your niece'.
